# ASP.NET P/Invoke "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

Tags: asp.net, pinvoke

I have an ASP.NET application that P/Invokes a 32-bit DLL.

When i deployed it on a 64-bit server i got the error "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".

Then i configured IIS to run 32-bit as per instructions given [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/405f5bb5-87a3-43d2-8138-54b75db73aa1.mspx?mfr=true). Still get the same error.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That only *allows* 32 bit applications to run, but it does't make anything actually run in 32 bit mode.

To use the 32 bit dll, your web application has to run in 32 bit mode, which is done by switching IIS to run in 32 bit mode. However, that might not be practically possible depending on what other web applications run on the server, as *all* web applications have to run in 32 bit mode. There is a link on the page that you linked to, that has more information about the implications of running IIS in 32 bit mode.

If you can't swtich to run IIS in 32 bit mode, you will need a 64 bit version of the dll to use it.

Comment: @Guffa How do you switch IIS to run in 32 bit mode?

Comment: @smkngspcmn: Look under "ASP.NET 2.0, 32-bit version" here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435/en-gb

Comment: @Guffa: Did that, didn't really help. And unfortunately a 64 bit version of the DLL is not available. I've read somewhere about compiling the project with target platform set to x86 instead of any platform. That didn't work for me either but could the problem be somewhere along those lines?

Comment: @smkngspcmn: In what way didn't it help? Did it fail, or can't you use it? Changing the target to x86 works for a desktop application, but not for a web application where IIS decides how it's run.

Comment: @Guffa: I started to run IIS in 32-bit mode and got the same error.

Comment: @Guffa: Please ignore my previous comment. Yous solution did in fact make it work, but the DLL did not get uploaded properly the second time around. Only realized when i noticed that file sizes were different.