# pass C# string to C++ dll fails in Release build

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling

I have a C++ dll with simple function like

```
#ifdef BUILDING_THE_DLL
#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
 ...
EXPORTED void AddSetting(char *key, char *value)
```

And a C# project with function declaration:

```
[DllImport("pers.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void AddSetting(string key, string value);
```

Everything works perfectly well while C# project is build in Debug mode. In Release build an exception is fired: "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

Any ideas?

**UPD:** In C# project Platform target was set to x86 in Debug mode and Any CPU in Release. I've changed to x86 in Release and it was the solution. Thanks a lot to Matt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need specify to use the ansi format of the string, by default. it is unicode. It should be :

```
[DllImport("pers.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet::Ansi)]
public static extern void AddSetting(string key, string value);
```

Also, if the function "AddSetting" modifies the strings, you need to use StringBuilder in C#. Please refer this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx) for details.

Comment: Setting ANSI didn't help. And function doesn't modify its arguments.

Comment: @SkySurfer can you show the source code of AddSetting?

Comment: AddSetting has one line of code - its a function call with const char* args. Its just a wrapper.

Comment: Now I wonder why it works without CharSet.Ansi in debug mode..
And what's the difference between debug and release builds in fact?

Comment: @SkySurfer another possible cause:  load a 64-bit dll into a 32-bit process, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811955/pinvoke-c-dll-from-c-sharp-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-inc